# nvidia gpu instruction cache size

Tags: caching, gpu

Anyone knows the instruction cache size for Nvidia GPU (both Fermi and Kepler)? I have tried to search a lot, but not too much such info is provided by Nvidia. There's one [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5452013&tag=1) describing how they benchmark Nvidia GT200 GPU. And there's also one [work](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~zeng/microbenchmarking/) describe the data cache in Fermi GPU, but it doesn't analyze the instruction cache.

Answer (score 0):

I can not access to any of the links that you provided. Please read this paper which performs micro benchmarking on GT200 GPU and reports the size of instruction caches (http://www.stuffedcow.net/files/gpuarch-ispass2010.pdf)